# When were random effects historically introduced to account for unobserved heterogeneity?

Tags: random-effects-model, history

In the course of doing some recent research on factors associated with exiting unemployment, I have found that only more recent papers try to account for unobserved heterogeneity using random effects, with older ones far more cautious about benefits and drawbacks of attempting to incorporate such a component.

For example, while paper [1] below debates the issue at length and ultimately decides not to account for unobserved between-subject differences, paper [2] includes random effects without much discussion, and compares results obtained with and without them.

Without wishing to get too deep, I was wondering what the seminal papers on random effects have been, and when they date back to.

[1] Narendranathan, W. & Stewart, M.B., 1993. Modelling the Probability of Leaving Unemployment: Competing Risks Models with Flexible Base-Line Hazards. *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series C (Applied Statistics),* 42(1), pp. 63-83.

[2] Rotaru, C.I., 2014. Transitioning Out of Unemployment: Analysis Using the ABS Longitudinal Labour Force Survey File. *Australian Journal of Labour Economics*, 17(2), pp. 111-137.

Comment: I would recommend defining "heterogeneity", which I don't think is used that way outside of economics.

Comment: Ok, but it would be good to know what you would use instead. "Unexplained variability" or perhaps "within-subject correlation"? These are useful, and may be de-facto synonyms, but neither is a direct conceptual substitute. What do you suggest?

Comment: I don't know, because I still don't know what economists mean when they say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its going to be hard to pin down as models involving random effects come out of a number of areas; repeated measures in the design literature,  multivariate analysis (especially with missing data), analysis of growth curves, and variance component analysis and Model II ANOVA (and likely more that I have neglected).

[Then there's the added difficulty in the different way terms like 'fixed effects' and 'random effects' are used in say econometrics vs biology. We need to be clear what we're talking about when we use some terms]

At the site "Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics", in the section on words starting with "V" (http://jeff560.tripod.com/v.html) it has under the entry on Variance/ANOVA

> The later literature found two models in Fisher's statistical work and produced contrasting terms for them. C. Eisenhart in "The Assumptions Underlying the Analysis of Variance," Biometrics, 3, (1947), 1-21 called them Model I and Model II analysis of variance. Eisenhart also used the terms fixed effects and random effects, though more informally. These appear with greater ceremony in H. Scheffé's "Alternative Models for the Analysis of Variance," Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 27, (1956), 251-271. Components of variance, another common term, was introduced by H. E. Daniels in 1939 in his "The Estimation of Components of Variance," Supplement to the Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, 6, 186-197.

Taking a quick look at Daniels' paper, he's clearly discussing models / situations with random effects.

So this suggests the term "Components of Variance" and models with random effects were being used no later than the 1930s. However old random effects models are, they're pretty old.

[Still backtracking. Based on the quote above, I am guessing we'd find Fisher perhaps at some time in the early 30s somewhere discussing random effects in relation to ANOVA]

Comment: Thank you for that overview. That makes it more than clear that the different approaches I have seen are a matter of different styles of approach rather than some concrete development over the last ten years. It's interesting how one researcher makes no fuss over an issue which for another is to be approached with great thoroughness.